# How much Physical memory does Alpha Zero's Neural Net require?

Tags: neural-networks, memory

I appreciate that there are many ways to arrange the memory in a NN, and that the numerical representations may be with bytes to floats depending on an implementation.  What is typical amount of memory required for the "application side" for the better NN programs such as Alpha Zero or an automated driving AI?  How much does it matter?